# Center colorbar Labels on Heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, colorbar

I have seen a few similar questions to this but haven't been able to make it work so I figured I would ask here.

I have a seaborn heatmap with 2 overlaid scatter plots. When it plots the colorbar the labels aren't centered on the colors. I was wondering how to center the values on the colors. Also is it possible to always set the 0 color as white? My code and plot is below

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))

plt.gca().set_aspect(RI/SI)
cbar_kws=dict(pad=0.01,shrink=0.86, drawedges=True, ticks=range(int(maxfold)+1)) #Colorbar size and location 

cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet', maxfold+1)

sns.heatmap(binspivot, cmap=cmap,linewidths=0.01, linecolor = 'black', vmin=0, vmax=maxfold, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False,annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 20,"color":"black"},cbar_kws=cbar_kws)
ax.set(xlabel=None, ylabel=None)
ax.scatter(Sourcedfcut['Xmod'],Sourcedfcut['Ymod'], color="red", s = 400)
ax.scatter(Recdfcut['Xmod'],Recdfcut['Ymod'], color="blue", s= 400)
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to have the tick marks of the colorbar at the center of the rectangles, is to move `vmin` and `vmax` by one half.  To add an extra color to an existing colormap, one can create a new `ListedColormap` using that new color and colors extracted from the original colormap. To make the white in the colorbar visible against a white background, a black surrounding rectangle can be added.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

binspivot = (12.02 * np.random.rand(20, 20) ** .5).astype(int)
maxfold = binspivot.max()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))

cbar_kws = dict(pad=0.01, shrink=0.86, drawedges=True, ticks=range(int(maxfold) + 1))  # Colorbar size and location

cmap1 = plt.get_cmap('turbo', maxfold + 1)
colors = ['white'] + list(plt.get_cmap('turbo', maxfold).colors)
cmap = ListedColormap(colors=colors)

sns.heatmap(binspivot, cmap=cmap, linewidths=0.01, linecolor='black', vmin=-0.5, vmax=maxfold + 0.5,
            xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False,
            annot=True, annot_kws={"size": 20}, cbar_kws=cbar_kws, ax=ax)
ax.set(xlabel=None, ylabel=None)
cbar_ax = fig.axes[-1]
cbar_ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
cbar_ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc='none', ec='black', clip_on=False, transform=cbar_ax.transAxes))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap, colorbar tick labels centered]